# Homebrew Issue with bundled libgit2 and git2go

Tags: go, homebrew, libgit2

I have a go application I am trying to distribute using Homebrew. When compiling without Homebrew everything works as expected. When using Homebrew I get a compile error.

Compile Error:

```
cannot load DWARF output from $WORK/github.com/libgit2/git2go/_obj//_cgo_.o: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short
```

This can be replicated by building my repo (which uses libgit2) on a mac from homebrew using:

```
$ brew install jwaldrip/utils/git-get -v --HEAD
```

The formula can be viewed at: 
https://github.com/jwaldrip/homebrew-utils/blob/master/git-get.rb

The Makefile the formula uses at:
https://github.com/jwaldrip/git-get/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: What version of homebrew do you have? (as in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29845). Did you try with XCode command line? (see http://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew). gcc from XCode used to be the only gcc supported (http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2132)

Comment: I have the latest homebrew installed. And I am not sure if this is a GCC issue. I am using apple gcc when I run make install independently. Did you try the commands I posted?